# Ambiguous column name error in order by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Why doesn't this query work?

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY DocumentID
        ) peta_rn
    , d.DocumentID
    , d.IsReEfiled
    , d.IGroupID
    , d.ITypeID
    , d.RecordingDateTime
    , dbo.GetLatestStatusDateTime(d.DocumentID) AS LatestStatusDatetime
    , dbo.FnCanChangeDocumentStatus(d.DocumentStatusID, d.DocumentID) AS CanChangeStatus
    , d.IDate
    , d.InstrumentID
    , d.DocumentStatusID
    , ig.Abbreviation AS IGroupAbbreviation
    , u.Username
    , j.JDAbbreviation
    , inf.DocumentName
    , it.Abbreviation AS ITypeAbbreviation
    , d.DocumentDate
    , ds.Abbreviation AS DocumentStatusAbbreviation
    , dbo.GetFlatDocumentName(d.DocumentID) AS FlatDocumentName
FROM Documents d
INNER JOIN IGroupes ig
    ON d.IGroupID = ig.IGroupID
LEFT JOIN ITypes it
    ON d.ITypeID = it.ITypeID
LEFT JOIN Users u
    ON u.UserID = d.UserID
LEFT JOIN DocumentStatuses ds
    ON d.DocumentStatusID = ds.DocumentStatusID
LEFT JOIN InstrumentFiles inf
    ON d.DocumentID = inf.DocumentID
INNER JOIN Jurisdictions j
    ON j.JurisdictionID = d.JurisdictionID
WHERE 1 = 1
```

whereas this one works:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY d.DocumentID
        ) peta_rn
    , d.DocumentID
    , d.IsReEfiled
    , d.IGroupID
    , d.ITypeID
    , d.RecordingDateTime
    , dbo.GetLatestStatusDateTime(d.DocumentID) AS LatestStatusDatetime
    , dbo.FnCanChangeDocumentStatus(d.DocumentStatusID, d.DocumentID) AS CanChangeStatus
    , d.IDate
    , d.InstrumentID
    , d.DocumentStatusID
    , ig.Abbreviation AS IGroupAbbreviation
    , u.Username
    , j.JDAbbreviation
    , inf.DocumentName
    , it.Abbreviation AS ITypeAbbreviation
    , d.DocumentDate
    , ds.Abbreviation AS DocumentStatusAbbreviation
    , dbo.GetFlatDocumentName(d.DocumentID) AS FlatDocumentName
FROM Documents d
INNER JOIN IGroupes ig
    ON d.IGroupID = ig.IGroupID
LEFT JOIN ITypes it
    ON d.ITypeID = it.ITypeID
LEFT JOIN Users u
    ON u.UserID = d.UserID
LEFT JOIN DocumentStatuses ds
    ON d.DocumentStatusID = ds.DocumentStatusID
LEFT JOIN InstrumentFiles inf
    ON d.DocumentID = inf.DocumentID
INNER JOIN Jurisdictions j
    ON j.JurisdictionID = d.JurisdictionID
WHERE 1 = 1
```

As you can see the only difference is I specify d.DocumentID. Is there anyway I can avoid having to specify `d.DocumentID` and instead specify only `DocumentID` without using an extra Select?  because after all, all documentID refer to the same value.

Comment: IF you find ambiguous column error , i think it should be the prob of particular column is present in multiple tables, DB server is failed to  retrieve the column from the particular table show you are supposed to specify the tablename.column name so it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `DocumentID` is in both tables `InstrumentFiles` and `Documents`, so how would the query engine know which one you are referring to?

So in short, **No**, you have to specify `d.DocumentID` in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

No.

you should have provided the alias `d` since multiple tables contains `DocumentID`. The engine gets confused on where (*or which table*) the order should be taken.